# Find names in list of strings and return pairs

Tags: python

My question is the following:
I have a list like:

```
list="In the end Tom loves Julie. Fred and Tina are a lot better with dogs.I don't think Jack and Jenny belong together."
```

First i made a function

```
def find_names(Sentence):
Sentence= [x for x in Sentence.replace(',', '').split() if x[0].isupper()]
return Sentence
```

With this i returned the words that start with a uppercase letter.

Now i must write a function

```
def find_pairs:
```

which should return a list of pairs in every sentence. If there are 3 capitalised words in a sentence,then it should remove the first (assuming that it is the first word of a sentence) and just return the other two. My return should look like this(example for list:)

```
[[Tom,Julie],[Fred,Tina],[Jack,Jenny]]
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Yes,the first funtion returns all uppercase words,now i just need names.

Comment: Probably worth checking out http://www.nltk.org/ and using that to extract nouns per sentence...

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding this, using NLTK would be like using a sledgehammer to put in a push-pin. He already has his list of candidate words, now he just needs to pick the most recent 2. Sounds like a list comprehension or for-loop to me.

Comment: yes this is kind of the case,i was thinking about using list comprehention from the start,but didn't know how to write it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a relatively messy list comprehension that should do the trick

```
>>> l = "In the end Tom loves Julie. Fred and Tina are a lot better with dogs.I don't think Jack and Jenny belong together."

>>> [[i for i in j.split() if i[0].isupper()][-2:] for j in l.split('.') if j]
[['Tom', 'Julie'], ['Fred', 'Tina'], ['Jack', 'Jenny']]
```

Comment: wow thanks a lot,i think it should do the trick ! I just need to ger rid of the commas after every name and that's it

Comment: is there an more elegant aproach to this? I am doing my best in writing less code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` to do such things

`l[0::2]` would take elements every 2 positions starting from 0,  same for  l[1::2] but starting from 1, and inverse them as we need to eliminate first elements in case the lenght is odd. we inverse using `[::-1]`

```
Sentence="In the end Tom loves Julie. Fred and Tina are a lot better with dogs.I don't think Jack and Jenny belong together."

l=[x for x in Sentence.replace(',', '').split() if x[0].isupper()]

print [[x,y] for x,y in zip(l[1::2][::-1],l[0::2][::-1])]
```

Comment: thank you for the anwser. I have been programing in c++ and c# before and i still have to get used to python. As you said zip and list slicing proves very handy in a lot of situtation. Python is great !

Comment: True! .Zip extension method is used in C# as part of LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

With a little modification,the end function looks like this:

```
def find_pairs(text):
return [names[len(names)==3:] for names in ([word.replace(",", "") for word in sentence.split() if word.istitle()] for word in text.split(".")) if 2 <= len(names) <= 3]
```